# x.findall function returns a value but won't write to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, dataframe, nltk

I've created a function that searches a NLTK.text.Text object, and returns a value when I run the function.

UPDATE: The problem seems to be that in the function below, the 'donation' variable is not actually being passed a value. The text.findall function however does return a value but doesn't update the variable for some reason.

```
def find_donation_orgs(x):
    text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
    donation =  text.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")
    return donation
```

The output something like this for the following input, however I think the output is from the text.findall and not the actual "return donation".

```
a = "This is a sentence. I also donate to Mr. T's Tea Party. I contribute to the Boys and Girls club. "

find_donation_orgs(a)
```

Output =

```
Mr. T 's Tea Party
the Boys and Girls club
```

However, when I try to apply that function in order to write the output to a new column in a pandas data frame, it's returning None. See below:

```
df['donation_orgs'] = df.apply(lambda row: find_donation_orgs(row['Obit']), axis = 1)
```

where df['Obit'] is a string of text similar to my a variable above.

UPDATE: So it appears that the output of a text.findall doesn't update the value of the variable its assigned to ... so I need to figure out how to actually assign that output to a variable in order to return it to a dataframe. See below:

```
text = df.text.iloc[1]

textfindall = text.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")

print('text is ' + str(type(text)))
print('textfindall is ' + str(type(textfindall)))
print(textfindall)
```

Output:

```
visit brother Alfred Fuller; the research of Dr. Giuseppe Giaccone at
Georgetown University
text is <class 'nltk.text.Text'>
textfindall is <class 'NoneType'>
none
```

Comment: `df['donation_orgs'] = df['Obit'].apply(lambda x: find_donation_orgs(x), axis=1)` ?

Comment: that code runs fine, and does create a 'donation_orgs' column but still returns None in every row for that column... I think its some sort of issue where my function is always returning a none type object even though the text.findall works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug your code by checking what your function actually receives and returns. You can either use a debugger (as found in most IDEs) or play around with your function's return value to ensure whether the problem lies with your function or the pandas functions

```
def find_donation_orgs(x):
    return x
```

to ensure your input is what you expected.

```
def find_donation_orgs(x):
    return nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
```

to see what tokenisation makes of it.

```
def find_donation_orgs(x):
    text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
    all_occurrences = text.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")
    if all_occurrences is None:
        return "no occurrences"
    else:
        return all_occurrences
```

to check whether your regex might be acting up. In which case, go back to the tokenizer output to try and fix your regex.

### Update

Looking at the [source code of the `nltk.Text`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html) object, it appears that the `findall` method does not actually return anything, but rather prints the results:

```
def findall(self, regexp):
    if "_token_searcher" not in self.__dict__:
        self._token_searcher = TokenSearcher(self)

    hits = self._token_searcher.findall(regexp)
    hits = [' '.join(h) for h in hits]
    print(tokenwrap(hits, "; "))
```

This is due to the fact that the `Text` object is only intended for use via interactive console:

> A wrapper around a sequence of simple (string) tokens, which is intended to support initial exploration of texts (via the interactive console). [...] If you wish to write a program which makes use of these analyses, then you should bypass the `Text` class, and use the appropriate analysis function or class directly instead.

Your function should look like this:

```
from nltk.util import tokenwrap
def find_donation_orgs(x):
    searcher = nltk.TokenSearcher(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
    hits = searcher.findall(r"<\.> <.*>{,15}? <donat.*|contrib.*|Donat.*|Contrib.*> <.*>*? <to> (<.*>+?) <\.|\,|\;> ")

    hits = [' '.join(h) for h in hits]
    donation = tokenwrap(hits, "; ")
    return donation
```

This replicates the original behaviour, except with an actual return value. Of course, you may want to format your output differently, once you have received the `hits` list.

Comment: so the first two output exactly what I want.

And so does the third one when I loop through using for x in df['Obit']: find_donation_orgs(x)... I get some no occurrences, which I expect, but I also get the correct values for the phrases that include "contrib" or "donat" however, when I write them to the dataframe every instance returns no occurrences

Comment: I had a look at nltk.Text().findall and it appears the actual problem is that the method does not in fact return anything, but rather just prints the result. I'll update my answer accordingly